# NHibernate: set id to interface mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I try to write a (fluent) mapping against an interface

```
public interface IOrderDiscount : IDomainObject<long>
```

where

```
public interface IDomainObject<IdT> : IDomainObject
{
   IdT Id { get; }
}
```

like so (and all other thinkable varieties of access strategies)

```
Id(d => d.Id, "DiscountId")
    .GeneratedBy.HiLo("9")
    .WithUnsavedValue(0)
    .Access.AsReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField();
```

but all I get are variations of

```
Could not find field 'id' in class 'IOrderDiscount'
```

My base class implements this as

```
public virtual IdT Id { get; protected set; }
```

but event using a backing field does not change a thing.

So I am left to wonder, how I could get this to work...
Anyone with an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the custom column name via the Column method instead:

```
Id(d => d.Id)
    .Column("DiscountId")
    .GeneratedBy.HiLo("9")
    .WithUnsavedValue(0)
    .Access.AsReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField();
```

Comment: Well, thanks, that was an old question :). Seems to me that was a bug or something like that, because, I am pretty sure the second param mapped to that column thingy, back then. Have you tried the original code (or something very similar) with a recent version of fluent?